# Why are the images in my carousel slider non-responsive?

Tags: jquery, css, responsive-design, carousel

I implemented the following carousel slider on my website and it looks perfect on desktop and laptop screens however when the screen widths are reduced, the image covers the entire screen and everything is nonresponsive.

I'm not entirely sure how to apply media queries to get the image to scale.

I believe all other portions of the website are responsive in the exception of the carousel and cant figure out how to get around making it work.

What could I have been doing wrong and how do I fix it?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  let $slider = $(".sliderG");
  let sliderItem = $slider.children(".item.active");
  let i = $slider.children(".item");
  let ind = 0;

  $slider
    .children(".item")
    .each(function() {
      $(this).attr("data-index", ind++);
    });

  i.on("click", function(e) {
    const that = $(this);
    let dataIndex = that.data("index");
    $(".item").removeClass("active");
    that.addClass("active");
  });

});
```

```css
.sliderG {
  width: 75%;
  height: 80%;
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0 auto;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 50px;
}

.sliderG .item {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  background: url(https://www.g-money.com.gh/wp-content/uploads/2019/06/squircle-minG.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  border-radius: 10px;
  transition: all ease 0.7s;
  z-index: 1;
  transform: scale(0.8);
  left: -300px;
  right: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.sliderG .item.active {
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 2;
  opacity: 1;
  background: #ccc;
  transform: scale(1);
}

.sliderG .item.active~.item {
  left: 0;
  right: -300px;
}

.sliderG .item.active+.item~.item {
  opacity: 0.3;
  visibility: hidden;
}

.sliderG .item.active+.item~.item:hover {
  opacity: 0.7;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='sliderG'>
  <div class='item'>
    <img src="https://www.g-money.com.gh/wp-content/uploads/2020/02/Sending-MoneyT-scaled.jpg" alt="G-Money Send Money">
  </div>
  <div class='item active'>
    <img src="https://www.g-money.com.gh/wp-content/uploads/2020/02/Generate-VoucherT-scaled.jpg" alt="G-Money Cash-Out at Agent">
  </div>
  <div class='item'>
    <img src="https://www.g-money.com.gh/wp-content/uploads/2020/02/Pay-MerchantT-scaled.jpg" alt="G-Money Pay Merchant">
  </div>
  <div class='item'>
    <img src="https://www.g-money.com.gh/wp-content/uploads/2020/02/Buy-AirtimeT-scaled.jpg" alt="G-Money Buy Airtime">
  </div>
  <div class='item'>
    <img src="https://www.g-money.com.gh/wp-content/uploads/2020/02/Bank-ServiceT-scaled.jpg" alt="G-Money Bank Account">
  </div>
  <div class='item'>
    <img src="https://www.g-money.com.gh/wp-content/uploads/2020/02/Withdrw-at-AgentT-scaled.jpg" alt="G-Money Withdraw at Agent">
  </div>
  <!--<div class='item'>
    <img src ="https://www.g-money.com.gh/wp-content/uploads/2020/02/Generate-VoucherT-scaled.jpg" alt="G-Money Pay Bill">
  </div>-->
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the below codes into the CSS

```
.sliderG .item img{
   display: block; 
   width: 100%
}
```